# further changes in Netty 5

Tags: java, netty

I am planning to use `netty 5.0.0.Alpha1` since I want to use the memcache codec.

However since it is an alpha version I was wondering if further changes to this version until the final release could not be backwards compatible.  In order words, if I set `5.0.0.Alpha1` as dependency in my project and then replace it for 5-final once it is released, could I break the code in my project?

Comment: Generally speaking you never want to use a alpha product in a production scenario. My advise is to use the stable current release and plan to use the new version when it is out and gone through a couple of cycles. Its never pleasant to explain to a director or executive that the software stopped working as you used Alpha versions for production. It is called a career limiting move or `CLM`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the memcache codec, you can always use 4.1.0. It's backward-compatible, and contains most new features of 5.0, including memcache codec.

At this point, there's no official release of 4.1.0, but I plan to release a beta version very soon.  Meanwhile, please use [the snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/netty/netty-all/).

Comment: thanks @trustin  How about stability of future beta version 4.1.0?  Is it stable enough to include it in a productive project?

Comment: I think its core is very stable.  The new features are not as well-tested as the core though.

Comment: 4.1.0.Beta1 is out now.

Comment: @trustin, when can we expect 5.0? I see there's been no update since December last year.